# My android app crashes randomly

Tags: android

I am new to android development and my app crashes randomly. Below is the log details.

```
03-27 01:18:17.399: I/Choreographer(13658): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 01:18:17.409: I/dalvikvm(13658): Could not compile trace for Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
03-27 01:18:17.409: I/dalvikvm(13658): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
03-27 01:18:17.409: I/dalvikvm(13658): JIT_INFO: Issues in trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
03-27 01:18:17.409: E/dalvikvm(13658): The following issues were seen:
03-27 01:18:17.409: I/dalvikvm(13658):  Issue: The trace provoked a spill
03-27 01:18:17.409: I/dalvikvm(13658): Trying less registerization from 1 to 0
03-27 01:18:17.409: I/dalvikvm(13658): Retrying trace Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
03-27 01:18:17.409: I/dalvikvm(13658): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
03-26 23:00:48.359: I/dalvikvm(12623): Retrying trace Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;updateWithOnConflict, offset 112
03-27 01:08:00.929: E/Watchdog(2301): !@Sync 204
```

Can anyone tell me what the error means.

Comment: Maybe you are doing much work on your main thread! Do your works on other thread and finally use main thread to update your UI.

Comment: what this error message 
03-27 01:59:52.409: I/dalvikvm(20476): Could not compile trace for Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7
03-27 01:59:52.409: I/dalvikvm(20476): ++++++++++++++
03-27 01:59:52.409: I/dalvikvm(20476): JIT_INFO: Issues in trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7
03-27 01:59:52.409: E/dalvikvm(20476): The following issues were seen:
03-27 01:59:52.409: I/dalvikvm(20476):  Issue: The trace provoked a spill
03-27 01:59:52.409: I/dalvikvm(20476): Trying less registerization from 1 to 0
03-27 01:59:52.409: I/dalvikvm(20476): Retrying trace Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7

Comment: I think you copied the wrong lines from the log. if it crashes there has to be an exception.